# Stream.CopyTo(Stream.Null)

Tags: c#, stream

I want to verify my ZipArchive. To do this I copy all entries to MemoryStream. I only want to find out whether I am capable of open and copy my entries.

```
    public void ZipVerification(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
            {
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    entryStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this method consumes my memory. Whether it is better to use Stream.Null instead of MemoryStream?

```
    public void ZipVerification(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
            {
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    entryStream.CopyTo(Stream.Null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure. MSDN only tells about calling Read or Write on Stream.Null, nothing about what happens during copy to Null. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.null(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying to a null stream will work and, as you found, won't require the extra memory to save the data from the stream.

You can check the `Position` of the underlying stream to see that it's actually consuming the stream:

```
public static void ZipVerification()
{
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        // Print stream position before.
        Console.WriteLine(stream.Position);

        foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                entryStream.CopyTo(System.IO.Stream.Null);
            }
        }

        // Print stream position after.
        Console.WriteLine(stream.Position);
    }
}
```